# Variable is not passing by

Tags: java

I am trying to  pass aF variable. But when debugging, it shows to have a value of 0. Any idea? below is the code I am using (Update: I included the whole code).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EOS {

//defining constants, input variables
public static final double GAS_CONSTANT = 8.3144598; //J K-1 mol-1
double criticalTemperature;
double criticalPressure;
double temperature;
double pressure;
double molecularWeight;

public EOS(double criticalTemperature, double criticalPressure, double temperature, double pressure, double molecularWeight) {
    this.criticalTemperature = criticalTemperature;
    this.criticalPressure = criticalPressure;
    this.temperature = temperature;
    this.pressure = pressure;
    this.molecularWeight = molecularWeight;
}

// calculation of A* and B* (values of "a" and "b" will be provided by subclasses)
public double aStar(double a) {
    return a * pressure / (Math.pow(GAS_CONSTANT, 2) * Math.pow(temperature, 2));
}

public double bStar(double b) {
    return b * pressure / (GAS_CONSTANT * temperature);
}

//calculation of Z Value. The idea is to form the cubic function of Z as follow:

public List<Double> calculateZ(double aStar, double bStar, double uValue, double wValue) {

    List<Double> solution = new ArrayList<>();

    double a, b, c, q, r, d;
    a = -1 - bStar + uValue * bStar;
    b = aStar + wValue * Math.pow(bStar, 2) - uValue * bStar - uValue * Math.pow(bStar, 2);
    c = - bStar * aStar - wValue * Math.pow(bStar, 2) - wValue * Math.pow(bStar, 3);


    q = (3*b-Math.pow(a, 2))/3;
    r = (2*Math.pow(a, 3)-9*a*b+27*c)/27;
    d = (Math.pow(q, 3)/27) + (Math.pow(r, 2)/4);


    if (d == 0) {
        double x1 = 2*Math.pow(-r/2, 1/3) -(a/3);
        double x2 = -2*Math.pow(-r/2, 1/3) -(a/3);
        double x3 = x2;

        double[] temp = {x1, x2, x3};

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            if (temp[i] > 0) {
                solution.add(temp[i]);
            }
        }

    } else if (d > 0) {
        double x1 = Math.pow((-r/2)+Math.pow(d, 0.5),1/3)+Math.pow((-r/2)+Math.pow(d, 0.5),1/3)-(a/3);

        solution.add(x1);

    } else {
        double theta = Math.acos((3*r/(2*q))*Math.sqrt(-3/q));

        double x1 = 2*Math.sqrt(-q/3)*Math.cos(theta/3)-(a/3);
        double x2 = 2*Math.sqrt(-q/3)*Math.cos((theta+2*Math.PI)/3)-(a/3);
        double x3 = 2*Math.sqrt(-q/3)*Math.cos((theta+4*Math.PI)/3)-(a/3);

        double[] temp = {x1, x2, x3};

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            if (temp[i] > 0) {
                solution.add(temp[i]);
            }

        }
    }
    return solution;
}
}
```

Here the subclass

```
import java.util.Collections;

public class Soave extends EOS {


public Soave (double aFactor, double criticalTemperature, double criticalPressure, double temperature, double pressure, double molecularWeight) {
    super(criticalTemperature, criticalPressure, temperature, pressure, molecularWeight);
    this.aF = aFactor;
    this.fW = 0.48+1.574*aFactor-0.176*Math.pow(aFactor, 2);
}

double aF;
double uValue = 1;
double wValue = 0;
double fW;

public double reducedTemperature = temperature / criticalTemperature;


public double bValue = 0.08664*GAS_CONSTANT*criticalTemperature/criticalPressure;
public double aValue() {
    double term1 = 1 - Math.sqrt(reducedTemperature);
    double term2 = 1+fW*term1;
    double term3 = Math.pow(term2, 2.0); 
    double term4 = Math.pow(GAS_CONSTANT, 2)*Math.pow(criticalTemperature, 2.0);
    return 0.42748*term3*term4/criticalPressure;
}

public double aStarValue = aStar(aValue());
public double bStarValue = bStar(bValue);

public double gasZValue = Collections.max(calculateZ(aStarValue, bStarValue, uValue, wValue));
public double liquidZValue = Collections.min(calculateZ(aStarValue, bStarValue, uValue, wValue));

public double gasDensity = pressure * molecularWeight / (1000 * gasZValue * GAS_CONSTANT * temperature);
public double liquidDensity = pressure * molecularWeight / (1000 * liquidZValue * GAS_CONSTANT * temperature);

}
```

So now when we create an instance of Soave for the following inputs, we should get for liquidDensity a value of 568.77

```
        double p = 500000;
    double t = 318.15;
    double pC = 3019900;
    double tC = 507.9;
    double aF = 0.299;
    double mW = 86;

    Soave soave = new Soave(aF, tC, pC, t, p, mW);
    System.out.println(soave.liquidDensity);
```

Comment: Show the code where you actually create your instance of Soave.

Comment: Please also show the code where you read `aF` - since it's a public non-final variable, is there any chance that you are writing `System.out.println(soave.aF = 0);`, or similar, thereby overwriting its value?

Comment: `When creating an instance of Soave, ...` where?

Comment: Where does your code say something like this: `Soave mySoave = new Soave(...)`

Comment: Please show real code that compiles. In the above code, the class *Soave* has no member *fW* but in some further code you access a member of that name.

Comment: @Codo Look again. It does have the fW member though it is located below the constructor. :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I overlooked it. And it's probably after the constructor because Abdulla thinks it will be executed after the constructor...

Comment: @Codo I updated the code to include the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your fW variable prior to actually setting the value of aF so it is using the default value of the primitive double which is 0.

Either create a getter for fW where you do the calculations or more the calculation for fW inside the constructor block.

So Either you do like this:

```
public class Soave extends EOS {
public double aF;
double uValue = 1;
double wValue = 0;
public double fW;

public Soave (double aFactor, double criticalTemperature, double criticalPressure, double temperature, double pressure, double molecularWeight) {
    super(criticalTemperature, criticalPressure, temperature, pressure, molecularWeight);
    this.aF = aFactor;
    fW = 0.48+1.574*aF-0.176*Math.pow(aF, 2); //This will give you the proper number.
}
```

Alternatively add a getter and do the calculation directly(No need for the fW-variable in the class then).

```
public double getfWValue() {
 return 0.48+1.574*aF-0.176*Math.pow(aF, 2);
}
```

If so then use that directly in your print-statement instead.

```
System.out.println(soave.getfWValue());
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked. But why it needs to be inside the constructor? Can't it be within the Soave class?

Comment: You can have it in a separate method as well. As long as you do the calculations after you have actually done the call to _new Soave(...)_. Otherwise _aF_ will Always be 0 since it won't be set prior to that.

Comment: I just debugged the cose and aFactor is the value that I input, but  aF is showing zero! Any idea?

Comment: aF will be zero until the line
    this.aF = aFactor 
is reached in the constructor. 
Zero is the default value of a double that has not yet been given a value.

Comment: Yes I agree however the breakpoint was further down line the program. I assumed that this.aF = aFactor is already executed by then

Comment: Update: I included the whole code so that you can see the issue that still there. aF is showing zero and hence fW zero as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is surely the matter of passing the argument or reading it. Look at the piece of code where you pass the value(Most likely you pass 0, it's quite "hard" to make it 0 while reading). If you still can't find your mistake, post the proper code here.